# NodeJS socketio race conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, socket.io, race-condition

I'm caching with socket io and I need to update my values ​​very quickly. (20 simultaneous requests), and at the end of it all, a get request to check, however, my get returns the value before the updates finish, that is, I expect a result of 20, and my get returns 10, 11, etc. I put a timeout in the catch function and it worked, but it is not very performant.

I've already tried using mutex, semaphore and lock, and it didn't work. Can anyone help?

heres the code:

```js
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server({});

var cache = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('clear', () => {
        cache = {};
    });


    socket.on('addToQueue', async (data, cb) => {
        if (data.type == `get`) {
            // function that await a time
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 20))
            cb({ value: cache[data.key] })
        }

        if (data.type == `transaction`) {
            //performs a calculation on each request and edits the cache
           var { balance, last_transactions } = cache[data.key];
            var {value, type, description} = data.value;

            if (type == 'd') {
                if (balance.limit < ((balace.total - value) * -1)) {
                    return cb({ value: {error: {type: tipo, error: `no-limit`}, ...cache[data.key]} })
                }
                balance.total -= value;
            }

            if (type == 'c') {
                balance.total += value;
            };

            let latest_transactions = last_transactions|| [];
        
            latest_transactions.push({
                value: value,
                type: type,
                description: description,
                created_at: new Date().toISOString(),
            })
        
            latest_transactions.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.created_at) - new Date(a.created_at));
            latest_transactions = latest_transactions.slice(0, 10);

            cache[data.key] = {
                balance,
                last_transactions: latest_transactions
            };

            cb({ value: cache[data.key] })
        }
    });
});

(async () => {
    io.listen(6456);
    console.log(`Server listening at *:${PORT}`);
})()
```

Avoid race conditions without making an unnecessary timeout every time.

Comment: If you know how many updates will be there, just wait until the last one is ready and then fire the get cb.

Comment: unfortunately the number of updates is random

Comment: Ok then and how do you expect to catch the race condition, when another update could happen at any time?

Comment: thats the problem, With my time in hardcoded, everything seems to flow normally and all the tests are passing, but the time is too high, I need to resolve this time out issue with the tests passing

Comment: Can there be way to have ‘type’ with values of starting and finishing with the transaction?

Comment: You are not showing us enough code here to understand what causes a race condition or what the criteria is that your  "get" request actually wants to wait for before returning the value.  If what you're really trying to do is make the "get" request wait until all incoming requests before it are done, then we will need to see the rest of the code for those other operations and probably you will need to implement a queue to ensure that GET requests are processed in order and not until prior requests are done.

Comment: One thing that's for sure is that a `setTimeout()` is a hack.  Not only is it not performant, but it's also unreliable if any of the operations it is waiting for just happen to be slower than the timeout for a moment.

Comment: exactly, timeout is not reliable at all. Basically, my test set fires several transaction requests without waiting for a response, and then at the end of it all, it sends a get (and waits for the response), but I don't know how many updates are made (it's random).

I edited the question showing the logic I execute in the transaction

Answer (score -1):

To handle the issue of race conditions and ensure that your get request returns only after all updates are finished, you can implement a more robust synchronization mechanism. Given that you've tried mutexes, semaphores, and locks without success, it seems the problem might be in the way these tools were applied rather than their suitability for the task.

One effective approach is to use promises and a counter to track the completion of all transaction operations before allowing the get request to proceed. This method avoids arbitrary timeouts, which can be both inefficient and unreliable.

Here's a revised version of your code that implements a basic promise-based synchronization mechanism:

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server({});
var cache = {};

// Counter to keep track of ongoing transactions
let ongoingTransactions = 0;
// Array to store resolve functions of promises waiting for transactions to complete
let waitingForCompletion = [];

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('clear', () => {
        cache = {};
        // Reset the counter and clear waiting list without resolving, as it's a reset operation
        ongoingTransactions = 0;
        waitingForCompletion = [];
    });

    socket.on('addToQueue', async (data, cb) => {
        if (data.type === 'get') {
            if (ongoingTransactions > 0) {
                // Wait for all transactions to complete
                await new Promise(resolve => waitingForCompletion.push(resolve));
            }
            cb({ value: cache[data.key] });
        } else if (data.type === 'transaction') {
            // Increment the counter at the start of a transaction
            ongoingTransactions++;
            try {
                // Perform the transaction...
                // This is where you'd modify the cache as per your transaction logic
                // For demonstration, let's simulate it with a timeout
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 20)); // Simulate async work

                // Decrement the counter when the transaction is complete
                ongoingTransactions--;
                if (ongoingTransactions === 0) {
                    // If there are no more ongoing transactions, resolve all waiting promises
                    waitingForCompletion.forEach(resolve => resolve());
                    waitingForCompletion = []; // Clear the waiting list
                }
            } catch (error) {
                // Handle any errors that occur during the transaction
                console.error("Error during transaction:", error);
                ongoingTransactions--;
                if (ongoingTransactions === 0) {
                    waitingForCompletion.forEach(resolve => resolve());
                    waitingForCompletion = [];
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

(async () => {
    const PORT = 6456;
    io.listen(PORT);
    console.log(`Server listening at *:${PORT}`);
})();
```

This solution uses a counter to track the number of ongoing transactions. When a get request is received, it checks if any transactions are ongoing. If there are, it waits by creating a new promise and adding its resolve function to an array. Once a transaction completes, it decrements the counter, and if no more transactions are ongoing, it resolves all stored promises, allowing the get requests to proceed and fetch the updated cache value.

This approach ensures that get requests will only proceed once all transactions have completed, without relying on arbitrary timeouts, thus improving both performance and reliability.

Comment: It's a great approach. However, I tried to implement it and now it only works with a time out in the transaction, which makes the overall time worse. I think I have some promise without await running, which makes the code not work as it should.

Comment: Very Nice answer, but using some NoSQL engine such as Redis, can Deal with Race conditions without Lock any request, and some backend service to persist redis data with some interval.

Comment: With redis it works well, but my latency increases by around 10ms, using the socket makes my response faster and I need the shortest response time possible for this application

Comment: @Fount I'm trying to figure out exactly what your expectations are.  You mentioned that 20 concurrent messages can come in and you want to be able to get a fairly accurate cache response where you're concerned about 10ms variance.

How fast do truely need your cache to be updated?  If you're pushing into high-frequency processes, I'd look at Flink for that.